# Scrolling across UITableviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a situation where I need to scroll across UITableViews. The number of UITableViews could be any number, it is dynamic. In that case which of the following implementation would be better, taking into account the memory intensiveness, UX and overall efficiency ?

1. To have a scroll view on which I put all the tableviews
2. To have a collection view on which I put the tableviews on each cell of the collection view.
3. or any other suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: collectionview is better option because you can reuse cell. in scrollview you can't.

Comment: you can also use single tableview with multiple sections

Comment: In what direction would you be "scrolling" between table views? Horizontally like pages, or vertically?

Comment: may be only collection view without table inside would be enough. Can you provide either image with example or name some apps which have already exist so we can have better understanding of what you are going to implement

Comment: @Mike Horizontal Direction

Answer (score 0):

TableView inside TableView or TableView inside CollectionView will be good approach other wise view reuse functionality has to implement by you.

As you say your data us dynamic 
instead of providing scrolling to inner and outer tableview you can populate data in inner tablView they will grow as much data is present and out tableview will contain these inner tableviews and serves as scrollview (provide scrolling/ pagination)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If, based on your comments, you want to have multiple table views that you can scroll horizontally between, I would highly recommend creating a page view controller where each table view is a page. If you're unfamiliar with how to create page view controllers, I have a little open-source project that makes it easy to build your own, or alternatively look at my code and replicate it.

https://github.com/mamaral/MAPageViewController